# No Bluetooth device was detected

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I want to install the **bluetooth** device on my laptop , but when I run the install shield wizard for `broadcom 2070 Bluetooth 3.0` for windows-7 I got this error message

`No Bluetooth device was detected`

How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: you have not told which brand of laptop you are using?

Comment: my laptop is hp G62

Comment: Is the device listed in the device manager? Is there an option to disable the device through a switch or a keyboard shortcut on this laptop?

Comment: @GurkenPapst the blutooth device not listed in the device manager!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the physical device is either not physically installed... or is switched off... or is broken... or the driver you're trying to install does not match the hardware.